# Geometrically interpreting quotient rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, ideals, quotient-group

I would like some help with geometrically interpret quotient rings using algebraic geometry. To explain my current understanding using an example, take:

$$  R=\mathbb{C} \left[ x, y, z \right] / \left( xy, yz \right) $$

It seems to be that if you mod out $xy$ so $xy=0$, then $x=0$ or $y=0$. Thus the algebraic subset of $\mathbb{C}^3$ corresponding to the ideal $\left( xy \right)$ is the union of the $x$ and $y$ axes.

Similarly, when we mod out the other equation, we are left with the union of the $y$ and $z$ axes.

What, then, does the ideal $\left( xy, yz \right) $ correspond to? The $x$, $y$, $z$ axes? Is it only the $y$ axis?

Is there some way to geometrically interpret $R$ overall, using similar reasoning in algebraic geometry?

This is where things get a little fuzzy. Any help in finishing off/clarifying the geometric interpretation of $R$ here would be great. Any advice/comments on how to interpret things like this in general would be welcome too

Comment: Have you taken a look at the coordinate ring of an algebraic affine variety?

Comment: To start with: $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ is not a plane with axes. It's the ring of polynomials in two variables with complex coefficients. That means the rest of your attempt to understand the quotient makes little sense.

Comment: Yes I understand that. I'm thinking more along the lines of using the Nullstellensatz (and related corollaries) to interpret the behavior of the quotient ring geometrically. Apologies, maybe I should have mentioned that more explicitly.

Comment: Maybe to help people understand my motivation: many algebraic geometers seem to use their geometric understanding of objects such as quotient rings to quickly and intuitively calculate things like maximal ideals in said quotient ring. This is my motivation for trying to 'visualise' rings like $R$ here using the Nullstellensatz.

Comment: There is no $z$ in $\mathbf{C}[x,y]$.

Comment: Whoops! Ok, fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a bijection between coordinate rings and affine varieties. In our case, that variety is $V= V(xy, yz)$. A point $x \in \Bbb C^3$ is in $V$ iff either its $y$-coordinate is zero or both its $x$- and $z$-coordinates are zero.

We can write $V = V(x, z) \cup V(y)$. Therefore $V$ is the union of the $xz$-plane and the $y$-axis.

Comment: Which can also be seen with $(xy, yz) = (y)*(x,z) = (y) \cap (x,z)$, and then use that $V(I \cap J) = V(I) \cup V(J)$.